# What does "remain solely" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Lifts are to remain solely under the control of the operator in the
>   platform.

What does "remain solely" exactly mean? Does it mean that there should be one lift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb phrase is "remain under the control (or supervision) of". "solely" means "exclusively".

The meaning of that sentence is that the operator will be the only person in charge of controlling lifts.